# solution of multidimensional PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm looking for a way to find a solution 'f' to the following PDE.

$$ y \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + g_1(r)\left(z\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right) + g_2(r)\left(y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = 0$$

$r\in [a,b]$, x, y and z are $]-\infty, \infty[$

I know $f(a,x,y,z)$ and $f(b,x,y,z)$. I also know that $f\to\infty$ for $x,y,z \to \pm \infty$, so I can impose $f(x_{\max})=f(y_{y\max}) = f(z_{z\max}) = 0$

The functions $g_1$ and $g_2$ are

$g_1(r) = \tanh(r)$

$g_2(r) = 1/\cosh(r)$

Comment: Have you tried using the method of characteristics? I think if you regrouped each term according to their partial derivative, you should be able to take it from there for an arbitrary initial condition

Comment: I'm not really aware of this method, I've found many references on the web for "method of characteristics" but not specific enough for me to understand what to do. Despite, why are you talking about "initial" condition and not "boundary" condition?

Comment: For instance in http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~corona/hw/PDE%20NOTES%20Shatah%2009.pdf, they assume the coefficients are non zero, but in my case y, g1, z and x can be zero

Answer (score 1):

$y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\tanh(r)\left(z\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)+\text{sech}(r)\left(y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}-x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=0$

$y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}+y~\text{sech}(r)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+(z\tanh(r)-x~\text{sech}(r))\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\tanh(r)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial r}+\text{sech}(r)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{z\tanh(r)-x~\text{sech}(r)}{y}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\tanh(r)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dr}{dt}=1$ , letting $r(0)=0$ , we have $r=t$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\text{sech}(r)=\text{sech}(t)$ , letting $x(0)=x_0$ , we have $x=x_0+\tan^{-1}\sinh(t)=x_0+\tan^{-1}\sinh(r)$

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=-\tanh(r)=-\tanh(t)$ , letting $z(0)=z_0$ , we have $z=z_0-\ln\cosh(t)=z_0-\ln\cosh(r)$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{z\tanh(r)-x~\text{sech}(r)}{y}=\dfrac{z_0\tanh(t)-x_0\text{sech}(t)-\tanh(t)\ln\cosh(t)-\text{sech}(t)\tan^{-1}\sinh(t)}{y}$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $\dfrac{y^2}{2}=\dfrac{y_0^2}{2}+z_0\ln\cosh(t)-x_0\tan^{-1}\sinh(t)-\dfrac{(\ln\cosh(t))^2}{2}-\dfrac{(\tan^{-1}\sinh(t))^2}{2}=\dfrac{y_0^2}{2}+z\ln\cosh(r)-x\tan^{-1}\sinh(r)+\dfrac{(\ln\cosh(r))^2}{2}+\dfrac{(\tan^{-1}\sinh(r))^2}{2}$

$\dfrac{df}{dt}=0$ , letting $f(0)=F(x_0,y_0^2,z_0)$ , we have $f(r,x,y,z)=F(x_0,y_0^2,z_0)=F(x-\tan^{-1}\sinh(r),2x\tan^{-1}\sinh(r)+y^2-2z\ln\cosh(r)-(\tan^{-1}\sinh(r))^2-(\ln\cosh(r))^2,z+\ln\cosh(r))$